# Compiling error with 'system' command using Theos

Tags: ios, theos, tweak

I try myself to create tweaks. I start with something simple. A tweak that just does a respring.

When I try to compile I have this:

[image: Error when try to compile]

My .m file:

```
-(void)respring {
    system("killall -9 SpringBoard");
}
```

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of text. Please [edit] your question and replace the picture with the actual text. Pictures can't be searched or referenced and they are much harder to read.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We prefer that questions be searchable, so others searching for the same problem as you find your question. To that end, please include your error here as text, rather than as an image, as images can't be searched for.

Answer (score 0):

I have added the following in my Makefile and the problem has been solved:

```
CFLAGS = -Wno-deprecated -Wno-deprecated-declarations
```